# Сервер для Java приложения

Tags: java

Все что мне нужно: запустить простой код на Java. Это Standalone - приложение: чат на сокетах. Перерыв много информации в интернете я понял что для сервера нужен выделенный ip. Получить его можно арендовав VPS. Арендовав VPS можно подключиться к нему через ssh, поставить туда Java, скопировать через scp исходники, запустить через ssh свой код который слушает определенный порт, и в коде клиента подключаться к ip сервера и порту. Я все правильно понял?

Код сервера

```
public void go() {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000); //мой VPS будет слушать порт 5000
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("new connection");
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Код клиента

```
private void setUpNetworking() {
    try {
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("myvps.blabla.com");
        sock = new Socket(ia, 5000); //Идем на порт 5000
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(r);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("Networking OK");
    } catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: да, вы всё поняли правильно. если это и есть ваш вопрос, то зачем приведён какой-то код?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Код привел на всякий случай. То есть я могу взять в аренду VPS например на digitalocean?

Comment: https://www.heroku.com